# Flutter: reauthenticate on resume

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to reauthenticates user before all the stateful widgets resume in Flutter?  I have multiple stateful widgets which does api calls on init state.  The problem is when the auth token expires, it would log the user out without giving it a chance to fetch a new auth token since these requests are concurrent.  I.e. When one request is fetching a new auth token, another request will not know and thus assume log the user out.  I want to make sure a loading screen which re-authenticates the user is shown before other stateful widgets are added back to the hierarchy on resume.

Comment: If you are using dio, you can use it's [lock/unlock feature](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio#lockunlock-the-interceptors).

Comment: @Vineet Thanks, I will keep it in mind.  I am not using Dio at the moment but might switch to it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out a way by pushing a new route on resume and disabling the back button.  Its quick enough that they use doesn't even see the screen.